# "TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float" when attempting to add values in an array

Tags: ruby

So I am just trying something simple, trying to add up all of the ages in my array using a loop. But for some reason it doesn't work when I type it out like this, what is the issue here? Laymans terms please since I am at the very beginning of my code journey.

```
   ages = Array.new

   ages[0] = 25
   ages[1] = 22.4
   ages[3] = 16.3
   ages[4] = 21
   ages[5] = 58.34
   ages[6] = 33.25

   total_years = 0.0

   ages.each do |age|

      total_years += age

   end
```

It works when I type the array out like below

```
ages =[25, 22.4, 16.3, 21, 58.34, 33.25]
```

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: "what is the issue here?" - you skipped one index, leaving its value as `nil`

Comment: For the future, "it doesn't work" tells us nothing. You're getting an error? Post that error in its entirety.

Comment: I edited your post to include a descriptive title. There's [an article on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that includes a section about writing good titles. A title like _Looking for some advice with my code (Beginner learning Ruby) - each iterations on arrays_ is not useful -- we know you're here for advice because this is a Q&A site; we don't need to know if you're a beginner or not; _each iterations on arrays_ does not adequately describe the problem you're having. Good titles attract good answers!

Answer (score 0):

You've skipped an index in your array, thus giving it a `nil` value that cannot be used in arithmetic.

Take a look at how your array looks after you populate it:

```
ages = Array.new

ages[0] = 25
ages[1] = 22.4
ages[3] = 16.3
ages[4] = 21
ages[5] = 58.34
ages[6] = 33.25
```

This gives you an array that looks like:

```
[25, 22.4, nil, 16.3, 21, 58.34, 33.25]
```

Now when you attempt to add the ages together, it looks like this:

```
25 + 22.4 + nil + 16.3 + 21 + 58.34 + 33.25
```

What happens when you add a Float and nil together?

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float
```

So make sure your array is fully populated, then try adding it together.

One way to avoid this error is to populate your array like this:

```
ages = [25, 22.4, 16.3, 21, 58.34, 33.25]
```

That way you don't have to worry about using the wrong index number when populating it.

Finally, you can add these values together much more easily using the Array `sum` method:

```
ages = [25, 22.4, 16.3, 21, 58.34, 33.25]
total_years = ages.sum
```

This returns:

```
176.29
```

Comment: Ohhhhh wow, I have completely missed that !! Thank you so much, also nice tip on the sum method. I was actually trying to make sure I understood the each method

Thank you thank you thank you !